# XSLT single and double quotes in form input value attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

Hopefully a quick question, how can I get this to be well formed, and therefore run?

```
<input type="rad" name="RadGroup" value="<xsl:value-of select="productOptionInfo"/>" />
```

I basically want to have a value placed inside of the attribute value, but they both need double quotes!?

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation why the currently selected answer is wrong and for two correct XSLT 1.0 solutions and another, XSLT 2.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In XSLT, there is a shortcut to use values within attributes:

```
<input type="rad" name="RadGroup" value="{productOptionInfo}" />
```

There is another option, which it to use `xsl:attribute`:

```
<input type="rad" name="RadGroup">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
       <xsl:value-of select="productOptionInfo"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

Comment: @Mac - I added some more options :)

Comment: Your first two tries are absolutely wrong. An attribute *cannot* contain unescaped markup. Please, verify your solutions by actually running them. I am not the downvoter who you are mentioning -- I just woke up this morning -- but he may just reacted to these flaws.

Answer (score 6):

**This is wrong**:

```
<input type="rad" name="RadGroup" 
       value="<xsl:value-of select='productOptionInfo'/>" />
```

**and this is wrong, too**:

```
<input type="rad" name="RadGroup" 
       value='<xsl:value-of select="productOptionInfo"/>' />
```

**In XML it is a syntax error to have (unescaped) markup as value of an attribute**. See the W3  XML Spec -- **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax)** and **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-attribute-types)**.

**The two correct ways to do this are** (called AVT or **[attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)**):

```
<input type="rad" name="RadGroup" value="{productOptionInfo}"/>
```

**and**

```
<xsl:attribute name="input">
  <xsl:value-of select="productOptionInfo"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

**In XSLT 2.0 one is allowed to write**:

```
<xsl:attribute name="input" select="productOptionInfo"/>
```

**The first way above is the shortest and most readable** when the name of the element is statically known (in advance).

**The second way has to be used when the element name isn't statically known** and must be generated with an `<xsl:element>` instruction.

Answer (score 4):

Use curly-bracket notation:

```
<input type="rad" name="RadGroup" value="{productOptionInfo}" />
```

Comment: Thanks that's got it working, you and Oded both gave me the right answer at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

You may use single quotes inside and double quotes outside, or vice versa.

Also, XML spec says:

> To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes, the apostrophe or single-quote character (`'`) may be represented as "`&apos;`", and the double-quote character (") as "`&quot;`".